# How to avoid resetting global variables set from userform for use in another module?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform in Excel with lots of options to select and values to enter. In the code for the userform I have several Public variables declared that store the info entered in the userform. When the user is done entering everything in the userform, they click the 'Process' button and the main function of the form is carried out (compiling data from several different Excel files into this sheet). After all the data is compiled, I have another command button on the first worksheet for running a summary report of the compiled data, which is put in another worksheet in the same workbook. The code for this summary macro is defined in Module 1 rather than in the code for the userform, since it is connected to a different command button. It seems that all my Public variables that are set in the code for the userform are reset when I run this summary macro, so nothing is working correctly.

Do I have to somehow link this module to the userform to be able to access those public variables? Or do I have to put the code for the summary macro in with the code for the userform? If that's the case, how do I call a Sub from the code for the userform in the code for the RunSummary_Click() command button code?

Comment: How many variables? Perhaps pass them as arguments?

Comment: You might try to run the form in non-Modal mode, so that you keep it alive (dont close it) after you compile the data. This way it stays alive while you can do other processing, such as the command button's action.

Comment: If none of the above help, you can put the values of the constants on the sheet in a hidden column, then call the values when the sub is run.

Comment: could you provide some code where you try, from Module1, to read the public variables of the UserForm? It might be the key to finding what is going wrong.

Comment: Hi @JWarren - just a general hint that you'll get a lot more useful answers if you post some code that people can look at, rather than reading your question and trying to picture it :) If you make a minimal example that shows the situation, you might even find yourself solving it by accident along the way by simplifying the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by running the userform as modeless (ShowModal = False) and declaring the Public Dim's of interest in the Module linked to the userform rather than in the userform code itself. Thanks for the help everyone.